# How to reboot Windows 8/10 and go to Advanced Boot options with WinAPI?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, windows-10

I know that one can reboot a workstation using [InitiateShutdown](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa376872(v=vs.85).aspx) API. I'm curious how to do I reboot and go to "Advanced Boot" option window that is available on Windows 8/10? (I'm asking about WinAPI or a registry setting.)

[image]

PS. The same can be achieved by calling:

```
shutdown \r \o
```

Comment: Since you know the command string to do it, can you just execute that command from the Windows API? As in, just run cmd.exe and pass it the string?

Comment: Adding on to what mock_blatt said, you can use the `system()` function from `<cstdlib>` to execute that command.

Comment: @xboi209: Calling `system()` will pop up a command prompt window, which is not generally desireable. And it provides pretty much no way to identify or even observe errors.

Comment: @IInspectable: None of the proposed methods will allow to observe errors.

Comment: @c00000fd: Using `CreateProcess` to launch *shutdown.exe* with redirected I/O streams would. Sort of.

Comment: @IInspectable: Yeah... and then what? Translating from the local output of whatever language happens to be installed for a user's UI. That's what I'm trying to avoid...

Comment: @c00000fd: I wouldn't translate output. It would probably be more robust to match the output against string table resources matching the current locale. Anyway, that was the *"sort of"* part anyway. And it was mentioned in passing, why `system` is inferior, in just about any respect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Windows 8 and up you can use the undocumented `dwShutdownFlags` value `0x400` that will initiate reboot and then show advanced boot menu options. That flag can be combined with `SHUTDOWN_RESTART`, `SHUTDOWN_RESTARTAPPS`, `SHUTDOWN_FORCE_OTHERS`, `SHUTDOWN_FORCE_SELF`.

As such:

```
DWORD dwResult = InitiateShutdown(NULL, NULL, 
    30,                                            //Use 30-second timeout 
    SHUTDOWN_RESTART | 0x400,                      //Reboot with advanced menu options
    SHTDN_REASON_FLAG_PLANNED | 
    SHTDN_REASON_MAJOR_APPLICATION |
    SHTDN_REASON_MINOR_OTHER);
```

Keep in mind though that this flag is undocumented, so use it at your own risk!

Comment: good job publishing this undocumented flag 0x400! I already assumed InitiateShutdown had a flag for this, but you saved me trying out all possible flags! It looks like this is the only place on internet where this flag is mentioned.